# How to use MobileFirst8 server for app developed in MobileFirst7.1?

Tags: cordova, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I've app developed in MobileFirst 7.1 SDK. Now i need to enable push notification behavior for this app(for both android and iOS). But i have only MobileFirst server 8 version. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 2):

The MobileFirst 7.1 client SDK is not compatible with the MobileFirst v8 server. The client side APIs, server endpoints have changed between MobileFirst 7.1 and 8.0. Therefore, you will need an app built with MobileFirst 8 SDK to work with a MobileFirst v8 server

Comment: Thanks @Srik. Is there anyway i can enable Push notification behavior for this app built in MF7.1 SDK?

Comment: You can refer to this link:https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/
to enable and configure push notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate your app to MobileFirst 8.

Check here for migration steps for applications and adapters from IBM Worklight Foundation 6.2 or IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 - 7.1, to IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/